# Linux CentOS sed command with regex issues

Tags: regex, sed, tabs, carriage-return

I have a txt file under CentOS in which I want to replace any `"\t\n"` with `"\t\t"`. I tried this:

```
sed -i -E 's/\t\n/\t\t/g' myfile.txt
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know if CentOS doesn't support regex in sed.

Any help is appreciated!

p.s.

Input(two lines):

1\t2\t3\t$
4\t5\t6\t$

Output(one line):
1\t2\t\3\t\t4\t5\t6\t\t

In Editplus, the find regex is '\t\n' and the replace is '\t\t'. Then all lines ending with '\t\n' will become one line, and each '\n' is replaced by one additional '\t'.

p.s.

my file is read like this (cat -A myfile.txt)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `perl` command to join lines if previous line has a single tab:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/(\S\t)\n(?!\z)/$1\t/g' excel.log
```

`(?!\z)` is a negative lookahead to fail this match for last line of the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223884/discussion-between-jonathan-zhou-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes.

```
sed -i -E  's/\\t\\n/\\t\\t/g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry this solution leaves the text file intact.

Comment: @JonathanZhou what version of sed do you have. I tried this out on CentOS 8 which has sed-4.5-1.el8.x86_64.

Comment: I am using CentOS 8 too. But I don't know what sed version is. May you please tell me what command to tell the version?

Comment: Just saw your update, this is only replacing the literal characters. It won't work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: In essence, there are multiple lines ending with \t\n. I would like to join the lines and replace \n with one additional \t. In Editplus, the find is '\t\n' and the replaced with '\t\t'. then it works fine in Editplus.

Comment: I mean my specific solution won't work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed